# Can total change in entropy be positive in a reversible process when there is non-PV work being done?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

Change in gibbs free energy is said to be equal to the -(non-PV work done by the system) for a reversible change when the temperature and pressure are constant.

$\Delta G=-w_{non PV,bysystem}$

However,

$\Delta G =-(T\Delta S_{total})$

where $\Delta S_{total}=\Delta S_{sys}+\Delta S_{surr}$

this would mean that for a reversible change the value for $\Delta S_{total}$ is non-zero when there is non-PV work bein done($w_{nonPV} \neq 0$)

Does this happen or am I wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Your statement of the criterion for maximum (reversible) non-PV work being equal to the change in total G of system plus surroundings is incorrect.  The criterion applies only to the $\Delta G$ of the system.  For the system plus surroundings, the change in entropy for this reversible process is zero.

Comment: The $\Delta G$ that I refer to is $\Delta G_{sys}$. 
...............$\Delta G_{sys}=\Delta H_{sys}-T\Delta S_{sys}=-T\Delta S_{surr}-T\Delta S_{sys}$......... since $\Delta S_{surr} = -\Delta H_{sys}/T$. Hence, $\Delta G_{sys}=-(T\Delta S_{total})$

Comment: In a reversible chemical process that goes from pure reactants in stoichiometric proportions, each at T and P, to pure products in corresponding stoichiometric proportions, each at T and P, part of the process is not at constant pressure.